# Obtener valores de un listview

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy intentando obtener los valores de un listview que tiene un edittext para que el usuario coloque los valores y yo los obtengo al momento de salvar la informacion. Ésto lo consegui; el problema es que utilizo *listview.getchildat(i)* y solo puedo obtener los hijos que son visible en la pantalla, pero a veces son mas de 50 hijos y no puedo obtener mas que los 8 visibles, quisiera ver si hay alguna manera de obtener los valores no visibles. Éste es el código que tengo y obtiene solo los hijos visibles:

```
 for (i = 0; i < feedList.size(); i++) {
                View v = lv.getChildAt(i);
                System.out.println("Posicion i: " + i);
                TextView cobro = null;
                try {

                    cobro = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.col_cobro);
                    System.out.println("CobroValidador: " + cobro.getText().toString());
                    sumaValidaCobro += Convert(cobro.getText().toString());
                    tstSuma += Convert(cobro.getText().toString());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    validaCobrado++;
                    System.out.println("Valida cobrado: " + validaCobrado);
              //      tstSuma += Convert(cobro.getText().toString());

                }
            }
```

feedList es el adapter inicial con el que se carga el listview, pero el usuario puede introducir los valores manualmente en el listview. Cuando guardo no puedo usar el original, necesito obtener todos los datos que el usuario introdujo.
 ¿Alguna manera de lograr esto?

Saludos.

Comment: Si tienes tantos hijos, quizás te interese usar mejor un RecyclerView y usar este método para obtener el ViewHolder del hijo según la posición. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(int)

Comment: Yo necesito obtener todos los hijos de ese Listview, tanto los que aparecen en pantalla como los que aun no se ven

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema.. Lo solucionaste

Comment: La manera que lo logre, fue cambiar de Listview a **RecycleView**, y a si me funciono correctamente